# "Insufficient permission" error while installing C# 3rd party application to WM Smartphone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

I am trying to install C# 3rd party application to Wm Smartphone, but I am getting insufficient permission Error. May I please know what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application needs to be signed or the phone needs to be unlocked.